# VB.net SpeechSynthesizer notify

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, speech-synthesis

I am using the SpeechSynthesizer() in VB.net

How can I detect when the speaker has finished speaking all its data?

I have this code:

```
        repetitionCounter = 0
        Do
            speaker.SpeakAsync(textIntroduction.Text)
            repetitionCounter += 1
            If repetitionCounter = repeatXNumberOfTimes Then
                MsgBox("Done")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
```

However, as soon as the Do starts, the MsgBox comes up straight away. I think this is because it loads the .SpeakAsync command into memory and as such, the repeatXNumberOfTimes is completed straight away.

I can change the code to:

```
      speaker.Speak(textIntroduction.Text)
```

This now works. However, the form 'locks up' and I cannot then interact with the form. I have tried implementing a Application.DoEvents(), yet the form still 'locks up'.

How can I get notified when the speaker has finished its speaking without locking the form up?

Also, If I want the speaker to play some text infinite number of times, how should I implement this?

**UPDATED*

Here is my code:

```
     Dim speaker As New SpeechSynthesizer()
     Public Event SpeakCompleted As EventHandler(Of SpeakCompletedEventArgs)
     Dim handler As EventHandler(Of SpeakCompletedEventArgs)
```

At the Form_Load(), I have added this code:

```
     AddHandler speaker.SpeakCompleted, handler
```

Is that how it should be done? Where do I write the code to be executed when the SpeakCompleted event is fired?

Comment: Why do you display a message box when you can *hear* it's complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be looking at the [SpeakCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakcompleted.aspx) Event:

From Link:

> The SpeechSynthesizer raises the SpeakCompleted event at the completion of any of the SpeakAsync() or SpeakSsmlAsync(String) methods. You can write handlers for the SpeakCompleted event using SpeakCompletedEventArgs.

---

You do not need to create an event, the events are already part of SpeachSynthesizer. Just create a subroutine that matches the event's signature and add it to the event like this simple Command Line example.

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

Module Module1
    Dim speaker As New SpeechSynthesizer()
    Sub Main()

        AddHandler speaker.SpeakCompleted, AddressOf SpeachComplete
        speaker.SpeakAsync("This is a test speach to see if the speach complete event raises")

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SpeachComplete(sender As Object, e As SpeakCompletedEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Speach Done")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I have edited my post. Where do I write the code to be executed when the SpeakCompleted event is fired?

Comment: @DarrylJanecek I added an example, give it a try let me know if you have anymore questions

Comment: The SpeachComplete sub gets called as soon as the SpeakAsync has read the code to speak, rather than at the end of the speech...

Comment: @DarrylJanecek It fires when the audio is complete on my computer, did you run my example ?